# USB-C port no longer receiving power

Tags: fedora, usb, power-management, laptop

I have previously been using USB-C to charge my Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 on Fedora 34 using the power adapter that came with the laptop. However, after using the USB-C port to transfer data from a hard drive, I can no longer use the port to charge my laptop.

I have tried rebooting, which does not fix the problem. The USB-C port still works if I plug a keyboard into it, however it does not receive any charge. I have no other way to charge the laptop.

Comment: If you run `lsmod | grep typec`, what does it show? There should be several USB-C-related modules loaded, like `typec`, `roles`, `typec_ucsi` and some hardware-dependent `ucsi_*` module, possibly `ucsi_acpi` (assuming none of those are built into the main kernel instead). Alternatively, see if `/sys/bus/typec/devices/` and `/sys/bus/typec/drivers` directories are empty or not. If those directories are empty, then kernel USB Type-C support does not seem to be active.

Comment: It does appear that both `/sys/bus/typec/devices/` and `/sys/bus/typec/drivers` are empty